# Is it possible to include a method in the interpolation of a string? (Swift)

Tags: swift, string-interpolation

I'm trying to include the `commercial()` method of my `Cars` class in the string interpolation performed by my `finalNegotiation()` method of my `PriceNegotiation` class. Is that possible?
I've tried using `.commercial()`, I also tried as you can see in this code I tried using `super.commerical()`

```
class Cars  {
    var make = ""
    var model = ""
    var year = 0

    init(carMake make:String, carModel model:String, carYear year:Int) {
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
    }
    func commercial() {
        print("This car is a \(year) \(make) \(model)")
    }

}




class PriceNegotation: Cars {
    var price:Double = 0


    init(desiredBuyerPrice price:Double,carMake make:String, carModel model:String, carYear year:Int ) {
        self.price = price

    super.init(carMake: make, carModel: make, carYear: year)


    }

    func finalNegotiation() {
        let dealerPrice = price * 1.5
        print("Since \(super.commercial()) the asking price is \(dealerPrice)")
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue here? This code compiles fine. BTW, you shouldn't usually call `super.foo()` from anywhere besides `self`'s own overridden implementation of `foo()`. It *really* complicates things, and easily leads to bugs and logical mistakes.

Comment: Also, two stylistic notes: 1) `Cars` is an inaccurate name. That class models only a single car, so it should be the singular, `Car`. 2) The parameter labels of the initialiaer are totally redundant. Imagine the calling code: `Car(carMake: "BMW", carModel: "i8", carYear: 2019)`. Car car car car. Consider instead: `init(make: String, model: String, year: Int)`, which leads to calling code like `Car(make: "BMW", model:'"i8", year: 2019)`. *Much* better.

Comment: Hi @CoderGab3 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `commercial()`, it prints the text and exits the function. To accomplish your goal, make the `commercial()` function include a return value. Here’s an example.

```
class Cars  {
    var make = ""
    var model = ""
    var year = 0

    init(carMake make:String, carModel model:String, carYear year:Int) {
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
    }

    func commercial()->String {
       return "This car is a \(year) \(make) \(model)"
    }
}
class PriceNegotation: Cars {
    var price:Double = 0

    init(desiredBuyerPrice price:Double,carMake make:String, carModel model:String, carYear year:Int ) {
        self.price = price

        super.init(carMake: make, carModel: make, carYear: year)
    }

    func finalNegotiation() {
        let dealerPrice = price * 1.5
        let commercialOutput = commercial()
        print("Since \(commercialOutput) the asking price is \(dealerPrice)")
    }
}
```

What this does is place the output of the `commercial()` function, a `String`, inside the other string via interpolation. Previously the function didn’t return anything so it appeared as though the function didn’t work. This, on the other hand, should work. Let me know if it doesn’t.